# How to change the "Data rate" of a video using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

How to change the Data rate of a video?

Those are what I have tryed:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i Video1.mp4 -b:v 284000 Video2.mp4
ffmpeg.exe -i Video1.mp4 -b:a 284000 Video2.mp4
ffmpeg.exe -i Video1.mp4 -bits_per_raw_sample 284000 Video2.mp4
```

Answer (score 1):

The `-b:v` flag sets the average bitrate, however for full control you should also specify `-maxrate`. `-bufsize` also allows you to choose how often ffmpeg calculates the maximum bitrate so for your example:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i Video1.mp4 -b:v 284000 -maxrate 300000 `bufsize 100000 Video2.mp4
```

Source: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Limiting%20the%20output%20bitrate

Comment: Thanks, but after I ran this `ffmpeg.exe -i Video1.mp4 -b:v 284000 -maxrate 284001 -bufsize 283999 Video2.mp4` I got a result Data rate of 238000

Comment: Perhaps try lowering the buffer size?

Comment: I will try that.